# How to select a single value from the list in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a data structure as follows.

```
Dictionary<Blopp, List<double>> data = ...;
```

One can see that it's kind of a list of dictionaries, really. And now, I'd need to access each of them independently. So I'm looking to get something like this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.First().Value.Count; i++)
{
  Dictionary<Blopp, double> partial = ...;
  // do stuff to the partial number i
}
```

How can I do that?

I've googled but it's a bit hard to explain in goolenglish what I'm looking for so I got jack. :(

**Edit**

Apparently, not only googling was confusingly hard to get, so, as suggested, I'm providing a data based example.

State before:

> { A:{q,w,e,r}, B:{a,s,d,f}, C:{z,x,c,v} }

State requested for the first iteration of the outer loop.

> { A:q, B:a, C:z }

State requested for the second iteration of the outer loop.

> { A:w, B:s, C:x }

State requested for the third iteration of the outer loop.

> { A:e, B:d, C:c }

In the above pseudo-example, capitals represent the keys while lower-cased correspond to the doubles.

Comment: You have one dictionary that contains key-List pairs.. You don't have a list of dictionaries

Comment: @user3185569 Yes, I know. But one **can** regard it as if I had a list of dictionaries, but imposed onto each other. Each element in the list of *Value* is more related to the elements in the other key-value pairs than what it is to its buddies in the same list.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: let's consider these 2 dictionaries : A:3|B:4|C:5 and A:2|B:9|C:7. Imposing one on the other you'll get : A:3,2|B:4,9|C:5,7... is that what you mean ?

Comment: @digEmAll Yesno. That's precisely the opposite of what I'm asking. I have {A:v1,v2,v3, B:v1,v2,v3, C:v1,v2,v3}. I need to get {A:vi, B:v1,C;vi}.

Comment: @GertArnold I can admit that at least one user got confused by the formulation and it's definitely less frequently needed algorithm. See the update in 5 minutes, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :

```
var firstEntry = data.First();
for(int i = 0; i < firstEntry.Value.Count; i++)
{
  Dictionary<Blopp, double> partial = data.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value[i]);
  // do stuff to the partial number i
}
```

Or you can turn into the whole data into a list of separated dictionaries using LINQ :

```
List<Dictionary<Blopp,double>> listOfDict = 
Enumerable.Range(0,data.First().Value.Count)
          .Select(i => data.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value[i]))
          .ToList();
```

**EDIT :**

Both of the previous approaches create a lot of throw-away dictionaries. This is of course less efficient and useless if you don't need to modify them and you only need to perform look-up's. So, I would go for an extension method exploiting some wrapper classes :

```
static class MultiDictionaryExtension
{
    #region Extension
    public static IEnumerable<IDictionary<TK, TV>> AsSeparatedDictionaries<TK, TV>(this IDictionary<TK, List<TV>> multiDict)
    {
        int numDictionaries = multiDict.First().Value.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < numDictionaries; i++)
            yield return new SingleDictionaryWrap<TK, TV>(multiDict, i);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Helper classes
    public class SingleDictionaryWrap<TK, TV> : IDictionary<TK, TV>
    {
        private class ValueCollection : ICollection<TV>
        {
            private readonly SingleDictionaryWrap<TK, TV> dict;
            public ValueCollection(SingleDictionaryWrap<TK, TV> dict)
            {
                this.dict = dict;
            }
            public int Count { get { return this.dict.Count; } }
            public bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }
            public void Add(TV item) { throw new NotSupportedException("This dictionary is readonly"); }
            public void Clear() { throw new NotSupportedException("This dictionary is readonly"); }
            public bool Contains(TV item) { return this.dict.Select(x => x.Value).Contains(item); }
            public void CopyTo(TV[] array, int arrayIndex) { foreach (var item in this) array[arrayIndex++] = item; }
            public IEnumerator<TV> GetEnumerator() { return this.dict.Select(x => x.Value).GetEnumerator(); }
            public bool Remove(TV item) { throw new NotSupportedException("This dictionary is readonly"); }
            IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return this.GetEnumerator(); }
        }

        private readonly IDictionary<TK, List<TV>> multiDict;
        public int Index { get; private set; }
        public SingleDictionaryWrap(IDictionary<TK, List<TV>> multiDict, int index)
        {
            this.Index = index;
            this.multiDict = multiDict;
        }

        public ICollection<TK> Keys { get { return this.multiDict.Keys; } }
        public ICollection<TV> Values { get { return new ValueCollection(this); } }
        public int Count { get { return this.multiDict.Count; } }
        public bool IsReadOnly { get { return true; } }
        public TV this[TK key]
        {
            get { return this.multiDict[key][this.Index]; }
            set { throw new NotSupportedException("This dictionary is readonly"); }
        }
        public bool ContainsKey(TK key) { return this.multiDict.ContainsKey(key); }
        public void Add(TK key, TV value) { throw new NotSupportedException("This dictionary is readonly"); }
        public bool Remove(TK key) { throw new NotSupportedException("This dictionary is readonly"); }
        public bool TryGetValue(TK key, out TV value)
        {
            value = default(TV);
            List<TV> values;
            if (this.multiDict.TryGetValue(key, out values))
            {
                value = values[this.Index];
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        public void Add(KeyValuePair<TK, TV> item) { throw new NotSupportedException("This dictionary is readonly"); }
        public void Clear() { throw new NotSupportedException("This dictionary is readonly"); }
        public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TK, TV> item)
        {
            TV value;
            if (this.TryGetValue(item.Key, out value))
            {
                return Object.Equals(value, item.Value);
            }
            return false;
        }
        public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TK, TV>[] array, int arrayIndex) { foreach (var kvp in this) array[arrayIndex++] = kvp; }
        public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TK, TV> item) { throw new NotSupportedException("This dictionary is readonly"); }
        public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TK, TV>> GetEnumerator() { return this.multiDict.Select(kvp => new KeyValuePair<TK, TV>(kvp.Key, kvp.Value[this.Index])).GetEnumerator(); }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return this.GetEnumerator(); }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Quite long extension class, but look how it makes everything simpler :

```
foreach (var partial in dict.AsSeparatedDictionaries())
{
    // use partial as a normal IDictionary<Blopp,double>
    // if you need the current "i" use partial.Index
}
```

---

**DISCLAIMER :**
All the previous codes assume that ALL the inner lists have exactly the same length.

Comment: They do. So much. It's always 12 because those are the months.   :)

Comment: The OP stated this in the other reply: _"So, to clarify. I'm not looking for a way to access the individual elements. I'm looking for a LINQ transform to obtain a dictionary containing a single element from the original list. The result won't have duplicate keys. It will have the same set of keys as the original one. But instead of a list of doubles it will have a single double (the one on position i)."_ - based on this comment, I believe what he's after is more along the lines of: `data.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value[1])` - same dictionary, but filtered down to a single double.

Comment: @MetroSmurf Yes, OP stated that. How does it relate to this answer? Am I missing a pitfall? It seems like a good content to me.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: added a new approach not wasting any memory, but just wraps the multidictionary ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you intended to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.First().Value.Count; i++)
{
    var partial = data.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ElementAt(i));

    Console.WriteLine("i={0}", i);
    foreach(var item in partial)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key={0}    Value={1}",item.Key, item.Value);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
i=0
Key=A    Value=q
Key=B    Value=a
Key=C    Value=z
i=1
Key=A    Value=w
Key=B    Value=s
Key=C    Value=x
i=2
Key=A    Value=e
Key=B    Value=d
Key=C    Value=c
i=3
Key=A    Value=r
Key=B    Value=f
Key=C    Value=v
```

Comment: This doesn't select a structure of type *Dictionary<Blopp, double> partial*. It simply iterates through all the elements. I was hoping for a LINQ to do that in a single swipe. Looping trough them all and creating a dictionary on the fly is the last resort.

Comment: @KonradViltersten You can do that.. I'll edit that answer. But not a dictionary, since a dictionary can't have duplicate keys !

Comment: So, to clarify. I'm **not** looking for a way to **access** the **individual** elements. I'm looking for a LINQ transform to obtain a **dictionary** containing **a single** element from the original list. The result won't have duplicate keys. It will have the same set of keys as the original one. But instead of a lsit of doubles it will have a single double (the one on position *i*).

Comment: @KonradViltersten Check the edit. I hope we're on the same page.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm miscommunicating the issue. If you unfold the *var* in the loop, you'll see that the *partial* in the sample isn't of the type requested. It's still just a single element, whereas I'm looking for a dictionary, however, reduced to a single double per instance of *Blopp*, instead of a list, as in the original.

Comment: @KonradViltersten *dictionary containing a single element* ? That's more like a `KeyValuePair`.. A dictionary of one element is like a purchasing a phone-book to save one phone number only

Comment: @KonradViltersten edit the answer to make it a dictionary, though it doesn't make sense unless you add more items to it.

Comment: The dictionary requested will not consist of a single element. It will have the same number of elements that the original one. However, instead of the values being a list of something, it should be just a single part of the original list. I know it's confusing so I added an example in the question. Feel free to give me some feed-back on how I can rephrase it to be more intuitively comprehensible, please.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Ok that makes sense now, check the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive this will do what you want. There may be a simpler way to do this and if I think of it I will update the answer, this code works even if the inner lists do not have all the same length.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<Blopp, List<double>> data = CreateData();

    List<Dictionary<Blopp, double>> result = PiviotDictionary(data).ToList();
}

private static IEnumerable<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>> GetSingleEntires<TKey,TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> data)
{
    bool foundValue = true;
    for(int i = 0; foundValue == true; i++)
    {
        foundValue = false;
        var result = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
        foreach (var kvp in data)
        {
            if (kvp.Value.Count > i)
            {
                foundValue = true;
                result.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value[i]);
            }
        }

        if (foundValue)
            yield return result;

    }
}
```